# Erro no 'content' do css

Tags: html, css

HTML e CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema :

O content do elemento p, não aparece na página, ele preenche o espaço, porém não aparece...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Valor do `content` é uma fonte requisitada? E se for, o uso correto deve estar em `:before` ou `after` do elemento de acordo com [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp). Exemplo:

```css
#app {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #666
}

#app:after {
  position: relative;
  content: 'div';
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">Qual a sua TAG?</div>
```

Comment: era exatamente por não estar no after, eu já havia resolvido antes de voltar aq no stack, mas obrigado mesmo assim :D